# Por qué se cambia el nombre de mis rutas en ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tengo definido la ruta de una acción en un controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
[HttpGet("/api/v1/​preguntas")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Question>>> GetQuestions()
 {
      return await context.questions.ToListAsync();
 }
```

Pero cuando hago la petición a esa ruta me devuelve un 404.

```
    http://localhost:53560/api/v1/preguntas
```

En cambio el servidor responde cuando el navegador me  cambia la ruta a:

```
    http://localhost:53560/api/v1/%E2%80%8Bpreguntas
```

Dentro del mismo controlador tengo otras métodos HTTP pero este es el único con esa anomalía, a que se debe?

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo dejo a modo de respuesta porque he visto en algunas ocasiones, por guiarse de tutoriales, copiar y pegar código de sitios web con otro tipo de codificación, genera problemas.

Si estás en este escenario, tendrías que eliminar `[HttpGet("/api/v1/​preguntas")]` y escribir nuevamente.